# Использование let в REPL

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, инструменты-разработчика

Если объявить переменную через let в строке, вызывающей ошибку `ReferenceError`, то потом использовать это имя переменной что-то не получается. `delete` не помогает.

```
let justSomeVar = itHaveNeverExisted // ReferenceError: itHaveNeverExisted is not defined
let justSomeVar = 0 // TypeError: Identifier 'justSomeVar' has already been declared
justSomeVar = 0 // ReferenceError: justSomeVar is not defined
```

Что можно сделать, чтобы нормально продолжать работать (без перезапуска nodejs) и всё-таки объявить переменную с этим именем?

Вервия nodejs 6.5.0.

В консоли Google Chrome 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit) та же проблема:

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: объявить выше по области видимости и использовать try/catch?

Comment: Эм.. Подразумевалось, что-то сделать позже. Т. е. ты что-то показываешь в консоли, случайно опечатываешься, получаешь `ReferenceError` и вместе с ним навечно занятое имя переменной? Хотелось бы как-то его освободить :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, забавно, но, похоже - никак. С другой стороны, что значит _освободить_? так как ты ее уже объявил, можешь просто присвоить значение так где надо

Comment: @Grundy, в том-то и дело, что не могу - 3я строка тоже даёт ошибку, что переменная не существует ;) А при попытке снова объявить ошибка, что она уже существует. Какое-то утёкшее имя получается... Первая строка хорошо ломает)))

Comment: @Qwertiy, ага, не понял сразу, пока не попробовал :-) Тогда, судя по всему - это может быть багом

Comment: Задай на enSO параллельно :)

Comment: кстати: [Chrome console already declared variables throw undefined reference errors for let](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41255090/2881286)

Comment: @Grundy, печалька: _"If top-level <script> execution throws an error, you have bigger problems than uninitialised variables."_

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41255090/4928642

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перевод [ответа @Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41256149/2881286)

---

Это происходит когда в глобальном скопе появляется временная мертвая зона. Как известно, `определения let` [всплывают, но остаются неинициализироваными](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/641285/186999). Из-за потока выполнения, в некоторых случаях переменные могут остаться вообще не инициализированными:

```
function …() {
    if (false)
        example; // при выполнении кинет исключение ReferenceError
    … // какие-то действия
    if (true)
        return; // выход!
    let example = 5; // никогда не выполнится
}
```

Все хорошо, если речь идет о функциональном скопе. Возможно, что-то пойдет не так, возможно, переменная вообще не понадобится - при следующем вызове будет создан новый скоп с новой переменной.

Что-то похожее происходит и в глобальном скопе, когда до инициализации переменной выбрасывается исключение (это единственная ситуация, способная прервать выполнение на верхнем уровне - никакие другие языковые конструкции так не могут).

```
throw new Error;
let example = 5;
```

В отличие от функционального скопа, в данном случае существенно, что переменная осталась неинициализированной. Глобальный скоп постоянен, и переменная **постоянно мертва**. Она никогда не будет инициализирована, и лексические переменные невозможно будет переопределить (что помогает предотвратить ошибки).

Эту ситуацию [обсуждали на es-discuss](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/toplevel-let-binding-can-be-left-permanently-uninitialized-after-an-error), но сочли проблему несущественной. Если при выполнении скрипта в top-level коде кидается ошибка, то у вас есть проблемы побольше, чем неинициализированные переменные. Восстановиться после этой ошибки невозможно. Если вам нужно что-то такое (например, попытаться переопределить переменную в успешных скриптах), то стоит использовать `var` в обоих местах.

То же самое происходит и в консоли.

Comment: Бррррр.. Какой-то очень корявый перевод...

Comment: @Qwertiy, в каких местах например?

Comment: Да во всех... Я что-то поправил - посмотри.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ага, некоторые места спорны, на мой взгляд, но в целом - лучше стало :)

Comment: А какие спорны?

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну можно и так :)

Comment: Просто ещё немного выпрямил :)