# Всплывают ли переменные, объявленные с помощью let и const в ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, hoisting

Проверяя новшества ES6, я обратил внимание, что переменные объявленные с `var` всплывают как и ожидалось...

```
console.log(typeof name); // undefined
var name = "John";
```

...в то время как, переменные объявленные с помощью `let` или `const` похоже имеют с подъемом некоторые проблемы:

```
console.log(typeof name); // ReferenceError
let name = "John";
```

и

```
console.log(typeof name); // ReferenceError
const name = "John";
```

Означает ли это, что переменные объявленные с помощью `let` или `const` не всплывают? Что происходит здесь на самом деле? Есть ли разница между `let` и `const` в этом случае?

---

<sub>Перевод вопроса: [Are variables declared with let or const not hoisted in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31219420/2881286)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31219420/are-variables-declared-with-let-or-const-not-hoisted-in-es6

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**tl; dr;** цитата из секции [13.3.1 Let and Const Declarations](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-let-and-const-declarations)

> The variables are created when their containing Lexical Environment is instantiated but **may not be accessed in any way until the variable's LexicalBinding is evaluated.**

---

> Переменные создаются когда инстанциируется содержащий их Lexical Environment, но **остаются недоступными никоим образом до вычисления их LexicalBinding.**

Так что, ответ на твой вопрос: да, `let` и `const` всплывают, но ты не можешь получить доступ к ним, до выполнения фактического определения в run-time.

---

Как сказано выше, эти переменные **не могут быть доступны**, до их объявления. Однако, все немного сложнее.

> Означает ли это, что переменные объявленные с помощью `let` или `const` не всплывают? Что происходит здесь на самом деле?

В JavaScript **все определения** (`var`, `let`, `const`, `function`, `function*`, `class`) **всплывают**. Это значит, что если имя определено в скопе, в этом скопе идентификатор всегда будет указывать на конкретную переменную:

```
x = "global";
// функциональный скоп:
(function() {
    x; // не "global"

    var/let/… x;
}());
// блочный скоп (не для `var`):
{
    x; // не "global"

    let/const/… x;
}
```

Это верно и для функционального, и для блочного скопов<sup>1</sup>.

Различие между определениями `var`/`function`/`function*` и `let`/`const`/`class` в их **инициализации**.
Первые инициализируются значением `undefined` или функцией (генератором) прямо когда создается связывание в начале скопа. Однако, лексически объявленные переменные остаются **неинициализированными**. Это значит, что при попытке доступа к ним будет брошено исключение `ReferenceError`. Инициализируются они. только в момент выполнения выражений `let`/`const`/`class`, все перед этим (выше) называется *временная мертвая зона (temporal dead zone)*.

```
x = y = "global";
(function() {
    x; // undefined
    y; // Reference error: y is not defined

    var x = "local";
    let y = "local";
}());
```

Обратите внимание, что выражение `let y;` инициализирует переменную значением `undefined`, аналогично выражению `let y = undefined;`.

*Временная* мертвая зона, это не синтаксическое место, а, скорее, *время* между созданием переменной (скопа) и инициализацией. Так, не будет ошибкой обращение к переменной в коде выше определения, пока этот код не будет выполнен (например тело функции или просто недостижимый код), но будет выкинуто исключение при попытке доступа к переменной до ее инициализации, даже если код доступа расположен ниже определения (например, во всплывшем определении функции, которая была вызвана слишком рано).

> Есть ли разница между `let` и `const` в этом случае?

Нет, они работают абсолютно одинаково, если рассматривать со стороны всплытия. Единственное отличие их в том, что `const`анты должны и могут быть присвоены только в части инициализатора определения (`const one = 1;`, вариант `const one;` с последующим присвоением значения `one = 2` недопустим).

---

<sub>1: естественно, определение `var` работает только на уровне функции</sub>

---

<sub>Переводы ответов [@thefourtheye](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31219489/2881286) и [@Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31222689/2881286)</sub>

Comment: Grundy, тебе интересно перевести статью про временную мертвую зону? Я нашел англоязычный вопрос-ответ думаю тебе понравится. Я его читал и там очень доходчиво объяснено. Сам бы перевел да думаю криво будет. Вот ссылка https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33198849/what-is-the-temporal-dead-zone

Comment: @MaximPro, там Bergi комментарий оставил, что тот вопрос хоть и не полный дубликат, но суть такая же как и в этом вопросе. В принципе, в трех последних абзацах тут, то же самое про эту зону указано.