# Области видимости JS

Tags: javascript

Почему внешняя глобальная переменная var value не меняется на true? Спасибо!

```
var value = 0;

function f() {
  if (1) {
    value = true;
  } else {
    var value = false;
  }
  alert( value );
}

f();
```

Comment: потому что в начале в функции всплывает `var value` в самый верх и является локальной переменной для всей функции... и меняется именно она

Comment: Спасибо большое, понял!

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Всплывают ли переменные, объявленные с помощью let и const в ES6?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/641284/186999)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вкратце, то в *JS* есть такая магическая вещь, как поднятие переменных.  Интерпретатор *JavaScript* всегда незаметно для нас перемещает (поднимает) объявления функций и переменных в начало области видимости.

Код

```
function test() { 
    someFunction(); 
    var x = 1; 
}
```

на самом деле интерпретируется так:

```
function test() { 
    var x; 
    someFunction(); 
    x = 1; 
}
```

В вашем случае происходит тоже самое, где область видимости одной переменной `value` является функция и в итоге происходит работа с локальной переменной.

Немного информации на тему есть https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types

и

[JavaScript и «поднятие» переменных и объявлений функций](https://habrahabr.ru/post/127482/)