# Область видимости переменной var

Tags: javascript, html, css

Почему я могу получить доступ к переменной `i` вне цикла, в котором она использовалась?

### Пример:

```js
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  console.log(i);
}

console.log(i, ' :вне цикла');
```

Comment: а почему ее должно быть нельзя использовать?

Comment: Потому что область видимости переменной ограничивается функциями, не циклами.

Comment: Похожий вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/693868/183458

Comment: потому что внутри цикла переменную нужно объявлять через let (то есть `for(let i = 0; i  <= 10; i++)`....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете получить доступ к переменной `i`, потому что она объявлена через `var`, а все переменные объявленные таким образом "*всплывают*" в начало родительской функции даже из вложенного блока.

### Как вы видите переменную `var`:

```js
function f() {
  if (true) {
    var variable = 10;
  }
  return variable;
}

console.log(f());
```

### Как интерпретатор видит переменную `var` на самом деле:

```js
function f() {
  //Начало функции
  var variable;

  if (true) {
    variable = 10;
  }
  return variable;
}

console.log(f());
```

Если вы хотите ограничить видимость данной переменной внутри цикла `for`, то используйте `let` вместо `var`.

---

### Живой пример:

```js
for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  console.log(i);
}

console.log(i, ' :вне цикла');
```

Область видимости переменной объявленной через `let` ограничена блоком, в котором она объявлена.