# Какая разница между объявлением класса через function и через class?

Tags: javascript, классы, объекты

Зачем нужно это:

```
function createClass() 
{
    this.name = "oneOfMyClasses";
}

var obj = new createClass();
```

Если есть это:

```
class myClass 
{
    constructor() 
    {
        this.name = "oneOfMyClasses";
    }
}

var obj = new myClass();
```

Какая разница между объявлением класса через `function` и через `class`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

На самом деле классы — это *"специальные функции"*, поэтому точно также, как вы определяете функции, вы можете определять и классы.  В JavaScript есть отдельные термины для таких объявлений:

- [class declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class)
- [function declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function)

**Разница** между объявлением функции (*function declaration*) и объявлением класса (*class declaration*) в том, что **объявление функции совершает подъём** (*hoisted*), в то время как **объявление класса — нет**. Поэтому вначале необходимо объявить ваш класс и только затем работать с ним. (Источник: [Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes))

> Поднятие задумывалось как общий способ мышления о том, как контекст
>   исполнения (в частности, фазы создания и исполнения) работает в
>   JavaScript. Однако, hoisting может привести и к недоразумениям.
>   Например, hoisting учит, что объявление переменной или функции
>   физически перемещается в начало вашего кода, хотя в действительности
>   этого не происходит. На самом же деле, объявления переменных и функций
>   попадают в память в процессе фазы компиляции, но остаются в коде на
>   том месте, где вы их объявили.

- [Поднятие (*hoisted*)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5)

`constructor` - специальный метод, служащий для создания и инициализации объектов, созданных с использованием `class`. Любая функция, вызванная через `new` становится конструктором и позволяет создать один объект.

Также будет полезно почитать:

- [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor)
- [new](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)

Comment: [объявления класса тоже всплывают, только немного специфично](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/641284/186999)

Answer (score 4):

```
// это было
function createClass() 
{
...
// когда этого еще не было
class myClass 
{
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Классы - это по сути синтаксический сахар в ES6. Под капотом все равно все происходит, как будто:

```
function createClass() 
{
```