# Есть ли смысл в IIFE? Нельзя ли их заменить анонимными блочными областями?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Не могу не испытывать отвращение к IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression). Если не брать в расчет модули, можно ли отказаться от них в пользу анонимных блочных областей? В чем принципиальная разница между ними?

**Пример IIFE:**

```js
var outsideTest = 'Меня видно';

var result = (function(){
  var insideTest = 'Меня не видно';
  console.log(outsideTest);
  
  return insideTest + ', если только так...';
})();

console.log(result);
console.log(insideTest);
```

**Пример с блочной областью** (ясно, что `var` здесь использовать не стоит):

```js
let outsideTest = 'Меня видно';

let result;

{
  let insideTest = 'Меня не видно';
  var anotherInside = 'Видно:('
  console.log(outsideTest);
  
  result = insideTest + ', если только так...';
}

console.log(result);
console.log(anotherInside);
console.log(insideTest);
```

Comment: Ну а если блок большой, и не виден на одной странице? Особенно если виден только хвост `}` — не понятно, это условие закончилось, или цикл, или что еще... а при встрече `})();` сразу понятно, о чем речь)

Comment: Ага, особенно если: `(function(whichIsTheHour){})("MGIMO finished?");` :) Такое не пропустишь). By the way, я заметил, что обычную функцию объявить нельзя в блочной области, только стрелочную. Или не так?

Comment: O_o можно... Заметил, что jsFiddle ругается на это. Но перестает, если записать блок с точкой-запятой впереди `;{  }`. P.s. пример IIFE переписал бы так: `let whichIsTheHour = "MGIMO finished?"; (function(){ /*пусть уж временную внешнюю переменную берет*/ })();` если нет вопросов с замыканием. А если есть - вероятно, обычная функция больше подходит.

Comment: Точно можно, но `;` не помогает, ругается и ругается. А IIFE просто для хохмы, чтобы заметней стало начало и конец. Тело я пропустил, чтобы не загромождать комментарии). Так собственно объявление именованной функции в блочной области позволяет использовать эту функцию за пределами блока, а IIFE - нет.

Comment: код в блоке нельзя рекурсивно вызвать

Comment: А как можно эту бяку рекурсивно вызвать? Здесь `result()`?

Comment: @Leonid, с блочной видимостью функции [не все так просто](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/945059/186999)

Comment: @Leonid, IIFE не обязана быть анонимной функцией: `(function a{ a(); })( )`