# "Куда" происходит всплытие переменной?

Tags: javascript, переменные, hoisting

Раньше думала, что всплытие происходит на самый верх области видимости переменной. То есть как тут. Так как переменная видна только в функции, то соответственно, объявление будет происходит в самом начале функции.

```
var foo = 1; 
function bar() { 
  //var foo; 
  if (!foo) { 
  var foo = 10; 
} 
console.log(foo); 
} 
bar();
```

Но уже здесь уже почему-то происходит объявление глобальной переменной, а не локальной.

```
//var a; 
function c() { 
a = 7; 
} 
c(); 
console.log(a);
```

Почему так работает?

Comment: Потому что отсутствует var

Comment: @andreymal что вы имеете в виду? var и там, и там отсутствует. Он же потом сам добавляется при всплытии, которое вызывает объявление

Comment: В первом случае вы явно написали var в строке `var foo = 10`, он и всплывает в начало функции. Во втором случае никакого var нет и его никто никуда не добавляет, и поэтому создаётся глобальная переменная

Comment: `window.a` либо `global.a` будут содержать 7. А это глобальные объекты, т.е. будут видны везде.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При присваивании выполняется абстрактная операция [`PutValue`](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-putvalue)

Как указано в спецификации в 5 пункте:

```
5. Если переменная не определена, то
    а. Если строгий режим
        i. Кинуть ошибку ReferenceError.

    b. Получить ссылку на глобальный объект.
    c. Установить в глобальном объекте свойство с именем соответствующим имени переменной и значением - соответствующим значению переменной.
```

Формально для браузера, код

```
function c() { 
  a = 7; 
}
```

Эквивалентен

```
function c() { 
  window.a = 7; 
}
```

В случае, если `a` нигде не объявлена.

Comment: То есть... правильно ли я понимаю: при hoisting'e объявление переменной всплывает на более высокий уровень вложенности? Из if выше - в саму функцию, а из функции (во втором примере) - на самый высокий уровень ( "а" становится глобальной переменной)

Comment: @Eva, нет не правильно. "всплытие" происходит всегда на том уровне где переменная объявлена. В случае var - это уровень функции, в случаях let/const - уровень блока. В случае в вопросе - "всплытия" вообще нет.

Comment: @Eva фигурные скобки ограничивают видимость для переменных объявленных с помощью let, const, переменные объявленные с помощью `var` - ограничены функциями

Comment: все, теперь понятно) спасибо!

Comment: И именно поэтому получается, что переменные объявленные с помощью let и const не всплывают, правильно?

Comment: @Eva, [переменные объявленные с помощью let и const тоже всплывают](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/641284/186999)

Comment: спасибо за ссылку) то есть если по-простому, переменная не может быть использована без инициализации. С `var` всплывает объявление и происходит инициализация на `undefined`, с let и const этого не происходит, поэтому всплытие let и const вызывает ошибку, так?

Comment: @Eva, ошибку вызывает не всплытие `let` и `const`, а попытка обратиться в неинициализированной переменной :)